# Wait with operation until Fragment's Views are created

Tags: android, transactions, android-fragments, android-service

I am programming a Music Player and the Music plays in a background `Service`. When the user kills the `Activity` which hosts 3 `Fragments`, and then restarts the `Activity` again, I send a `Broadcast` from the `Service` that contains information about the current playing song, and the list of songs that the user added to his session.

The problem is, every time I want to set the last information into the `Fragments` nothing happens because their creation takes too long, and the `Broadcast` doesn't get handled like they should.

How can I let the `Service` or the `Broadcast` wait until the Fragments are created so they are handled appropriately?

Here are the relevant code snippets:

```
//When the activity binds to the service, refresh the fragments
private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        myService.setBound(true);
        if(myService.startedOnce) {
            myService.refreshFragments();
        }
        myService.startedOnce = true;
    }
}

//This is the broadcast receiver of the Fragment
//it receives the broadcast too soon, and I can't set the
//Views so they are always empty.
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(MusicService.REFRESH_ALL)) {
        Song current = intent.getParcelableExtra("song");
        setCurrentSong(current);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How I fixed this

As I was using a Service for Media Playback, I wanted to bring up last listened songs from the service so I could directly play it. This was old logic, but I actually built my code around it. Until thusfar I bumped into it.

#### This was happening

- `FragmentActivity` is created
- `Service` gets started and bound to
- Meanwhile the `Fragments` get created asynchronously
- As soon as the `Service` starts, it sends out a `Broadcast` with latest information
- Because the both the `Service` and the `Fragment` creations are asynchronous, the broadcast would be sent from the service, but because the `BroadcastReceivers` in the `Fragments` weren't even initialized yet, they would not receive the `Intent`.

#### What I did to fix it

I somehow had to use a callback that made sure that

- the Service was created and bound to
- the fragments created and views are set

So I used the `ServiceConnection` and to be precise, the `onServiceConnected()` method. There I got the preferences in which the last song was saved, and then send out the `Broadcast` and the `Fragments` received it and the `Views` were appropiately set. This also worked for orientation changes.

#### The code

```
//This is the code in the FragmentActivity
private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        myService = binder.getService();
        myService.setBound(true);
        if (myService.startedOnce) {
            myService.refreshFragments();
        } else {
            sendLastSavedSong();
        }
        myService.startedOnce = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        myService.setBound(false);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14):

The easiest thing to do would simply be hold on to the information until the Fragment is ready to display it.  Use the Fragment's `setArguments()` method to attach the information into the Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onReceive() {
   String action = intent.getAction();
   if(action.equals(MusicService.REFRESH_ALL)) {
      // Creating a new Bundle so the Fragment can control its own object
      Bundle args = new Bundle(intent.getExtras()); 
      Fragment fr = getUsingFragment();
      fr.setArguments(fr);
   }
}
```

Then, in the Fragment's `onCreateView()` simply pull the arguments from `getArguments()` and build the view with the values.

```
@Override
public void onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   Bundle args = getArguments();
   if(args != null) {
      // code to set values if arguments are set
   } else {
      // code to set values if arguments are not set
   }
}
```

Another way to do it would be to use setter methods in which the Fragment itself puts values into a Bundle for `setArguments()`.  That way, you can update the views whenever the View has been created on top of setting the arguments for the possible event when the Fragment's View is destroyed and must be recreated.

Note:  You can only call `setArguments()` before the Fragment has been attached to the Activity.  You can however update the Bundle that you pass in by `setArguments` by retrieving a reference to it from `getArguments()`, then simply putting in the values.  So instead of calling `setArguments()` from your receiver, do something like this:

```
public void setCurrentSong(Song extra) {
   Bundle args = getArguments();
   args.putParcable(KEY_MAP, extra);
   if(/* Views are created */) {
      // update and invalidate the views
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm thank you for your well explained answer. I will try your approach too and think about the best answer again.

Comment: what is `getUsingFragment()`? That method does not exist for the v4 support `Fragment` nor the stock `Fragment` class.

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot to clarify. It doesn't exist. That's simply whatever method you use to get the fragment.  You can replace that with `findFramgentByTag()` or whatever method you have to retrieve the fragment you want to update. I was trying to make it more general because there are multiple ways to retrieve a fragment.

Comment: I actually fixed my problem by moving all fragment creation code to the `ServiceConnection` inner class in my `FragmentActivity`. It assured that all fragments were created and the service was started. I'm not sure which answer to accept now though.

Comment: You can't accept your own answer, but it would be best to answer your own question with the solution you used in case someone else finds it.

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase.  You can accept your own answer, but the bounty will not be given to you.  I believe it gets trashed.

Comment: @DeeV you are really awesome dude! Thanks a Ton!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something in the fragment like

```
Song current=null;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(MusicService.REFRESH_ALL)) {
        current = intent.getParcelableExtra("song");
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    if(current!=null) setCurrentSong(current);
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: This does not work. When I'm in `onResume()` the `current` variable is null which causes `NPE`, and if I check for null, it doesn't get set. This is because I send the `Broadcast` from the `Service`, which has not yet completed the sending of said `Broadcast`.

Comment: So the onReceive is received after the onResume apparently.  According to the fragment lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle, all views should have been created when calling onResume (and a fortiori when onReceive is called).  Can you elaborate on what goes wrong when calling setCurrentSong from within onReceive? The Views should exist afaics.

Comment: I have moved all fragment related creation code to the `onServiceConnection()` of the `FragmentActivity` and only that fixed the order in which everything works. So your assumption that the Fragment's `BroadcastReceiver` first receives the broadcast and then moves to the `onResume()` was technically wrong.

Comment: My assumption was based on your comment in your code stating "it receives the broadcast too soon, and I can't set the Views so they are always empty." which suggested that the onReceive was called before the views were created. The first test (first two comments here) indeed indicate that the onReceive is called after the onResume.

Comment: Yes, but as I was doing something wrong, my comments were wrong too ;) So I'm sorry but I can't accept this as an answer, for someone else might try to implement this code and it might not fully work.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was just creating your own callback interfaces. At the very end of onCreateView method of ur fragment just call your callback method, which tells ur mainactivity that the creation is done.

It worked for me, hope helps u too.